# WHM 11.28.87 / CENTOS 5.5, how to add custom services

Tags: linux, service

I have a custom background process (service) for our app (on Linux).  I am hoping I can get cPanel to monitor/control the process.

I tried adding an entry to /etc/chkserv.d/chkservd.conf, based on this [presentation](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/pub/AllDocumentation/TrainingResources/TrainingSlides07/Customizing_cPanel.pdf&rct=j&q=cpanel%20custom%20services%20monitoring&ei=6zmSTezGCpC5hAeM9MGODw&usg=AFQjCNEPRL08loKmZyCeozpELg_Km_1lPQ&sig2=-JQzFNyR1H01iH-0lKUd9g&cad=rja) - but I think its for a newer version as chkservd.conf does not match the layout shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this: http://arunjoshy.wordpress.com/6-2/

Comment: The chkserv.d stuff looks hopeful - will try that out.  Wonder if it will pick up new services without restarting...

Comment: I personally wouldn't leave my monitoring to chkservd, what happens if that fails? You may wish to consider external monitoring, for example use OPManager to monitor the process to increase detection reliability, if the process fails have the monitoring software restart the process via SSH. (Alternative applications will do the same)

Comment: Thanks - its early days for us, opsmanager maybe a good solution in the long run though.

Comment: This might be a better solution for you: http://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html

Comment: Because of link rot, please try not to answer questions here with a URL. You should answer the question here and can provide additional links for reference/additional reading. (No, I didn't downvote you.  I see you are new so this is just helpful advice.)